# kubernetes dashboard will not load

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-dashboard

I am **completely new** to Kubernetes, so go easy on me.

I am running `kubectl proxy` but am only seeing the JSON output.  Based on [this discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2011) I attempted to set the memory limits by running:

```
kubectl edit deployment kubernetes-dashboard --namespace kube-system
```

I then changed the container memory limit:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    metadata:
    ...
  spec:
    containers:
    - image: k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.8.1
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      livenessProbe:
        ...
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
      ports:
      - containerPort: 9090
        protocol: TCP 
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1Gi
```

I still only get the JSON served when I save that and visit http://127.0.0.1:8001/ui

Running `kubectl logs --namespace kube-system kubernetes-dashboard-665756d87d-jssd8` I see the following:

```
Starting overwatch
Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
Using service account token for csrf signing
No request provided. Skipping authorization
Successful initial request to the apiserver, version: v1.10.0
Generating JWE encryption key
New synchronizer has been registered: kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system. Starting
Starting secret synchronizer for kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder in namespace kube-system
Initializing JWE encryption key from synchronized object
Creating in-cluster Heapster client
Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
Serving insecurely on HTTP port: 9090
```

I read through a bunch of links from a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Metric%20client%20health%20check%20failed%3A%20the%20server%20could%20not%20find%20the%20requested%20resource%20(get%20services%20heapster).%20Retrying%20in%2030%20seconds.&oq=Metric%20client%20health%20check%20failed%3A%20the%20server%20could%20not%20find%20the%20requested%20resource%20(get%20services%20heapster).%20Retrying%20in%2030%20seconds.&aqs=chrome..69i57.214j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on the error but nothing really worked.

Key components are:

- **Local**:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- **minikube**: v0.28.0
- **Kubernetes Dashboard**: 1.8.3

Installed via:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Halp!

Comment: What are you running your cluster on gcloud/aws?

Comment: Just minikube locally.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using the minikube dashboard? You can reach it by:

```
minikube dashboard
```

Also you will get json on http://127.0.0.1:8001/ui because it is deprecated, so you have to use full proxy URL as it states in the dashboard github [page](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard).

If you still want to use this 'external' dashboard for some future not minikube related projects or there is some other reason I don't know about you can reach it by:

```
kubectl proxy
```

and then: 
 http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

- note that in the documentation it is `https` which is not correct in this case (might be documentation error or it might be clarified in the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-dashboard) part which I suggest you read if you need further information on web UI).

Hope this helps.